# postgresql creating rules on columns?

Tags: postgresql, rules

I need to format my SELECT queries on a text column. How may I do it without expliciting inserting it together with the query?

Do i use a rule in this case? I have tried creating a rule on the tables' column but apparently it won't work.

```
create or replace rule t_format AS ON SELECT TO site_ss_last_entry2
    DO INSTEAD
        select internet_date(site_ss.last_entry2) from site_ss;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a VIEW and SELECT from this VIEW to get what you're looking for.